# Finding multiple "most common values" in a column

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I am trying to display the 5 most commonly appearing text values in a column in Google Sheets.

The following will give me the most common value in column A:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(A:A,MODE(MATCH(A:A,A:A,0))))
```

And this will give me the *second* most common value in column A, assuming that the formula above is in cell G2 (whose result is being excluded):

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(A:A,MODE(IF(A:A<>G2,MATCH(A:A,A:A,0)))))
```

How can I get the third, fourth, fifth, etc most common values? Something like

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(A:A,MODE(IF(A:A<>G2:G3,MATCH(A:A,A:A,0)))))
```

does not work.

Basically I need to exclude multiple values from that calculation. Any ideas?

Comment: As `ArrayFormula` is not an Excel function I am assuming you're operating in Google Sheets? I've taken the liberty of removing the Excel tag from your Question.

Comment: Thanks, although my understanding is that the meat of this function still works in Excel as an array formula. It would just need to be entered with `Control + Shift + Enter ` and then would end up being formatting with curly braces instead of `ArrayFormula`, so something like `{=INDEX(A:A,MODE(MATCH(A:A,A:A,0)))}`. If this is correct, I think my question is still relevant to Excel.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Google Sheets and Excel are not identical.  As Alex M indicates, Excel doesn't even support this.  Google Sheets is off-topic on this site.  I've voted to migrate it to our sister site Web Apps, where it's on-topic.  The differences create a lot of wasted time and frustration when questions are posted on the wrong site, trying to figure out why problems can't be replicated or solutions don't work.